# Error while importing CSV file to cassandra - Not able to randomly generate UUID field

Tags: cassandra

I'm using Cassandra 3.9 :

```
copy mastertable(uniqueiduuid,alert,bvalue,cvalue,copysysopts,dbcparms,ddirectory,dfilename,display,ddir, ifile,localvalue,pvalue,ropts,rjobopts,idvalue,space,tdirectory,tfilename,unit)  from 'master.csv' WITH DELIMITER = ',' AND HEADER = TRUE;
```

> Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse uuid() : badly
>   formed hexadecimal UUID string.

**Note** : uniqueiduuid uuid PRIMARY KEY

Data in master.csv.

```
UNIQUEIDUUID,IDVALUE,PVALUE,IFILE,CVALUE,DDIRECTORY,DFILENAME,TDIRECTORY,TFILENAME,COPYSYSOPTS,DCB_PARMS,DDIR,ROPTS,RJOBOPTS,ALERT,BINARY,LOCALVALUE,DISPLAY,SPACE,UNIT
uuid(),3441,ACBSASPSYSICD300,ACBS_.+.FOC.THFPLUS.TEST.ROAD_NERCO.([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{6}).txt,WIRRCNT,,ABCD.SSPD.NOCER.T.$2$3$1$4.txt,,,strip.blanks(no)datatype(binary),,,,,ignore_Sev4~C03069567~ABC_DEF_Ops_ABD_BNM@google.com,YES,NO,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

> There's no way to do that directly from CQL's COPY command, but
>   instead you could process the CSV file outside of Cassandra first.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25801014/5978781

Comment: Sure, is there a way to auto-increment values for a column automatically in cassandra. The reason i have opted for UUID due to primary key. I have another unique column called IDVALUE, thinking if there is an approach to auto-increment this value at every new record, then i dont need UUID column at all. Any advice please

Comment: After the import of the csv file, for every new records inserted into Cassandra DB...is there an approach to have autoincrement column values.

Comment: I dont't understand your problem the exception is caused by uuid() - change that to a explicit uuid generated on your client side.

Comment: thank you. i have another field : which is an integer. values are 100,101,102.. i would like to get this value incremented while inserting each row. please advise.